# How can I refresh Kivy screen on button press

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating a Tic Tac Toe game using Kivy. I want to first provide the basic things the app does so it gives an idea of how my app works. The app currently has multi-user login support. Many players can sign up and their information will be stored and can be used for later (using an external .txt file). The game also saves individual player scores to another .txt file. The app has many different screens like the signup screen, login screen, high scores screen, settings screen, etc.

When someone signs up, their info like name, email, and password are stored in a login_info.txt file. At the same time, their name and an initial score of 0 are stored in a highscores.txt file. If a player wins a game, the zero is incremented by 1 and again saved to the high scores file.

I am showing the settings screen below:
[image: settings screen]

The "Manage Players" screen is the main topic of this question.

[image: Manage Players screen]

When I click on "Remove a player", a popup appears:

[image: deletion popup]

Clicking on "Delete a player" does a few things:

- Removes the given player's name, email, and password from the login_info.txt file
- Removes the player's name and score from highscores.txt file
- Dismisses the popup

So the main question here is after the popup is dismissed and the player is gone from both the .txt files, the "Manage Players" screen still shows that player's name and the button to remove it. When I close the app and then run the app again, then I see that the player whom I removed earlier is gone. I want to improve this. I want the player and its button to disappear immediately as the information is deleted from the .txt files. So is there any way to "loading" or "refreshing" the screen once the "delete player" button is pressed so that the screen is reloaded and since the screen reads data from the .txt files, it won't show the player since we deleted him. Another way I think might be to clear the screen (maybe with `self.canvas.clear()`?) and then read the .txt files and add the player names and their buttons again to the screen.

This is my code for the Manage Players screen. This is quite big and might have confusing code, that's why I have written about what happens when someone signs up or what deleting a player essentially does.

```
class ManagePlayers(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Creating an inside Layout allows the player names and buttons to be
        # on one layout and the "back" button to be on another layout.
        self.inside = GridLayout()

        self.file = open("login_info.txt", "r")
        self.inside.cols = 2
        self.inside.rows = len(self.file.readlines())
        self.file.close()

        self.highscores = open("highscores.txt", "r")
        self.file = self.highscores.readlines()[1:]
        # Here we are reading all the scores of each players and also 
        # converting them to integers and stripping of 
        # the newline character
        self.scores = [int(entry.split(",")[1].strip("\n")) for entry in self.file]
        self.highscores.close()

        with open("login_info.txt", "r") as file:
            file_contents = file.readlines()[1:]
            file_contents = [content.strip("\n") for content in file_contents]

            buttons_dict = {}
            labels_dict = {}

            def manage_player_deletion(instance):
                pop_up_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(10))

                deletion_message = Label(
                    text="Are you sure? You cannot undo this.", color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
                pop_up_layout.add_widget(deletion_message)

                yes_button = Button(text="Yes delete the player")
                no_button = Button(
                    text="I changed my mind. The player can stay!")

                pop_up_layout.add_widget(yes_button)
                pop_up_layout.add_widget(no_button)

                def delete_player(fake_instance):
                    # The parameter is named "fake_instance" so that it 
                    # doesn't get mixed with the main
                    # "instance" in the outer function manage_player_deletion

                    for label in labels_dict.values():
                        if label.text in instance.text:
                            for data in file_contents:

                                # Stripping the whitespace between first and last name
                                # This code removes player from login_info.txt
                                if label.text.replace(" ", "") == "".join(data.split(",")[0] + data.split(",")[1]):

                                    with open("login_info.txt", "r") as f:
                                        lines = f.readlines()

                                    with open("login_info.txt", "w") as f:
                                        for line in lines:
                                            if line.strip("\n") != data:
                                                f.write(line)


                    # This code removes player from highscores.txt
                    with open("highscores.txt", "r") as f:
                        lines = f.readlines()

                    with open("highscores.txt", "w") as f:
                        for line in lines:
                            name, _ = line.split(",")

                            if name not in instance.text:
                                f.write(line)      


                    deletion_message.text = "Success! This popup will dismiss any time now."
                    deletion_message.color = [0, 1, 0, 1]

                    Clock.schedule_once(popup.dismiss, 0.5)

                popup = Popup(title='Player deletion confirmation', title_size=(30),
                              title_align='center', content=pop_up_layout,
                              size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                              auto_dismiss=False)

                yes_button.bind(on_press=delete_player)
                no_button.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)

                popup.open()

            for count, content in enumerate(file_contents, start=1):
                first, last, *_ = content.split(",")
                name = first + " " + last

                labels_dict["player_label_" + str(count)] = Label(text=name)
                buttons_dict["remove_butt_" + str(count)] = Button(
                    text=f"Remove {name}", on_press=manage_player_deletion)

            for label, button in zip(labels_dict.values(), buttons_dict.values()):
                self.inside.add_widget(label)
                self.inside.add_widget(button)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.cols = 1
        self.go_back = Button(text="Go back to settings", size_hint=(
            0.8, 0.19), on_press=self.back_to_settings)
        self.add_widget(self.go_back)


    def back_to_settings(self, instance):
        tic_tac_toe.screen_manager.current = "Settings Page"
```

Thanks and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your 'delete_player()` method your are searching through the `Labels` to find the one that should be deleted. Can you just use `remove_widget()` to delete it? And use a similar search to find and delete the `Button`?

Comment: Yes! It really worked!! I just had to add two lines of code. After the label and the button is matched (`if label.text in instance.text`), then I had to add `self.inside.remove_widget(instance)` to remove the button and `self.inside.remove_widget(label)` to remove the corresponding label.